# Как создать домашний каталог пользователя без непосредственного входа в Windows?

Tags: c#, windows, администрирование, процесс, users

Необходимо создать домашний каталог существующего (только что созданного) пользователя заранее, до того, как он впервые войдёт в ОС. Есть один рабочий вариант, как это сделать в консоли:

```
runas /user:<Имя пользователя> rundll32
```

Представленный код запрашивает в консоли пароль пользователя и после правильного ввода создаёт домашний каталог. Проблема в том, что мне не подходит запрос пароля в консоли. Нужно обязательно сделать это через окно, а т.к. `runas` не поддерживает никакую передачу пароля ему, кроме непосредственного ввода с клавиатуры в консоль, вариант, представленный выше, оказывается неприемлемым.

Дополнение:

Выяснил, что домашний каталог создаётся при запуске любого процесса от имени нужного пользователя. Однако при запуске процесса `rundll32` из C# с помощью класса `Process` (да, процесс точно был запущен, проверял через Procmon) каталог всё равно не был создан.

Вопрос: какие есть способы проделать необходимую операцию, не прибегая к способу, описанному выше?

Answer (score 5):

Проблема решена. Нужно было всего лишь включить загрузку профиля пользователя в C# (в runas она включена по умолчанию). Делается это такой строкой:

```cpp
//...Предыдущие настройки по типу proc.StartInfo.xxx = yyy; и т.д.
proc.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Возьмите [psexec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) из комплекта microsoft sysinternals:

```
psexec -userUserName -p UserPassWord "rundll32"
```

Comment: Спасибо, но это всё же отдельное ПО, которое придётся дополнительно устанавливать на все компьютеры, которые будут использовать мою программу. Неудобно. Хотел обойтись только встроенными средствами и Visual C#.

Comment: @V-Mor Не придётся. psexec умеет в удалённый запуск.
`psexec \\marklap"c:\long name app.exe"`
https://www.itprotoday.com/compute-engines/psexec

Comment: Я понимаю, я имею в виду программу, которая будет запускать psexec. Ведь она должна будет его постоянно видеть, а следовательно его придётся распространять вместе с ней.

Comment: Ну если у вас чисто локальная дистрибуция, тогда да. Хотя она весит сущие копейки. А вот если надо по сети на кучу машин, вот прям в онлайне, что-то поставить-настроить, то милое дело. SysInternals utilities от Марка Русиновича штука старая, надёжная и полезная.